# phpMyAdmin message "The mbstring extension is missing." but php7.1-mbstring is installed

Tags: apache2, phpmyadmin, mariadb

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Apache 2.?
- MariaDB 10.0
- PHP 7.1
- phpMyAdmin ?

The apache2 "It works!" page appeared when I used a web browser to go to

```
http://localhost/
```

But when I browsed

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

the phpMyAdmin icon appeared in the browser title bar and the message "The mbstring extension is missing." appeared in the canvas. I tried

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php
```

and got the same thing. *However,* `php7.1-mbstring` *is installed!*

In Nautilus, I browsed to `/var/www/html`, that is, DocRoot, but there is no `phpmyadmin/` folder there! Shouldn't there be a `phpmyadmin/index.php` file in the doc root (web root?)?

How come I am even *getting a message* from phpMyAdmin in the browser? And how do I fix the mbstring issue?

Comment: The `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf` file sets up a redirect to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` when you access `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`. But I still don't know how to fix the error message about `php-mbstring` missing when it is actually present.

Comment: My question about the location of the phpMyAdmin is a duplicate of [link](http://bit.ly/2iKRMcU), although the answers to that question suggest creating a symbolic link at DocRoot to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`.

Comment: How did you install `phpmyadmin`, this will determine where your `phpmyadmin/index.php` is.  But I suspect you installed it using`sudo apt install phpmyadmin` so it should be in that link in your comment. For the `module` issue creating a `info.php` with this content `<?php echo phpinfo();  ?>` and place it in `/var/www/html/` then access it in the browser like so `localhost/info.php` and check to see if that module is enabled.

Comment: try this `sudo a2enmod mbstring` and re-check

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, mbstring for PHP 7.1 was installed and enabled yet phpmyadmin was telling me otherwise.

We were both right, mbstring for 7.1 *was* installed but apache was running on PHP7.0 after the upgrade, so I swapped PHP versions...

```
a2dismod php7.0
a2enmod PHP7.1
```

restarted apache2 and all was good.

(this happened right after a release-upgrade to 17.10 which reported some issues)

Comment: How did you determine which version Apache was using?

Comment: I ran phpinfo() in a browser >> 

PHP Version  7.1.15-0ubuntu0.17.10.1

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php7.3
```

worked for me, I had installed php7.0 just before realizing I needed 7.3 and had to remove it but I had a feeling something was still referring to the old PHP, this fixed it.